# CPanel Cron Job settings for working days

Tags: cron, cpanel, job-scheduling

I am new to cron jobs, and I wanted to create a cron job which will not run on weekends, like Monday to Friday once in a day at 9:00AM. I am not sure about the format. Any suggestion or help please.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
0 9 * * 1-5 comand

Minute Hour Day Month Weekday
```